# How do I find out all the users who favorite a particular tweet of mine? How can I find in Twitter API call?

Tags: twitter, favorites

I need to see who favorited my tweet. I need Twitter API call to know who favorited my tweet and the person details.

Comment: [Questions about API calls are generally off-topic here](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/740/are-api-questions-on-topic-or-off-topic).

Comment: This was [asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368684/twitter-api-how-to-get-users-id-who-favorite-specific-tweet).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a Twitter API call at present to find out who favorited a tweet. You could attempt to pull the information out of one of the live stream APIs as discussed [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/661) and similar to [this FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6898), although the data is real time and not historical. [Favstar](http://favstar.fm/) already does this, so you could have a look at that (it has a [rudimentary API](http://favstar.fm/api) that may help).

Bear in mind that you won't see favorites of users who protect their tweets with any of these methods though.